# coap protcol real time data processing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, coap

I have a generic question, I would like to know if there is any framework to allow coap based paylaods to be proceed in realtime.

is kafka/storm a valid candidate?

any tutorial/link is highly appreciated.

my client is a coap based sensor sending data with coap (writen in c )

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't actually know what coap is, but for real time stream processing you might not even need storm on top of Kafka, since the kafka-streams are around. take a look at this video I think you will get a better taste of what kafka can do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7zSLNiTZbA.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is two separate things - the CoAP implementation and data processing.

For example, you may use the Californium as a CoAP server which will forward your data to a processing system.

http://www.eclipse.org/californium/